# How to compute $\int_{\mathbb S^2} e^{-i\left<t,\omega\right>} \, e^{-i\left< A(\omega)x,y\right>} \, d\sigma(\omega)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, special-functions, matrix-analysis, fourier-transform

I would like compute the following
$$I_{t,x,y} = \int_{\mathbb S^2} e^{-i\left<t,\omega\right>}  \, e^{-i\left< A(\omega)x,y\right>} \, d\sigma(\omega); $$
where $\mathbb S^2$ is the  two-dimensional sphere, $t\in \mathbb R^3, \,  x,y\in \mathbb R^4$ and $A(.)$ is the matrix given by $$ A(s_1,s_2,s_3):= \left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    0 & s_{1} & s_{2} & s_{3} \\
    -s_{1} & 0 & s_{3} & -s_{2} \\
    -s_{2} & -s_{3} & 0 & s_{1} \\
    -s_{3} & s_{2} & -s_{1}& 0
  \end{array}
\right)$$
for all $s_1, s_2, s_3 \in \mathbb  R$.

Comment: Kirillov's character formula

Comment: @ Hassan Jolany, How this formula can be adapted to my case?

Comment: $S^2$ is coadjoint of $SU(2)$

Comment: @ Hassan Jolany, how can use the example of $SU(2)$ given in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirillov_character_formula  to compute $I_{t,x,y}$ ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can get the answer with elementary means by direct calculation.

Define $A^*(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\langle A(\omega) x, y\rangle = \langle A^*(x,y), \omega \rangle$. Also, let $z = t + A^*(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Now, parametrize the $2$-sphere in the usual spherical coordinates, such that the polar angle $\theta = 0$ is aligned with $z$ and hence $\langle z, \omega \rangle = |z| \cos\theta$:
$$
  I_{t,x,y} = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_{-1}^{1} d(\cos\theta) \,
    e^{-i|z|\cos\theta}
  = 4\pi \frac{\sin|z|}{|z|} .
$$